# J2ME App in Blackberry Network connectivity issue

Tags: jar, blackberry, java-me

I have developed a J2ME App which i tried in Blackberry device. Application launched successfully but when i am making a network call its throwing exception. Currently the Blackberry device which i own doesn't have BIS(Blackberry Internet Service) plan enabled. I am testing it in Blackberry OS version less than six.

Here is my Coding for HTTP Get Method

```
public static Vector httpGet(String uri, String param) {
    Vector buf = new Vector();
    try {
        String parameter = param;
        String url = uri + "?" + parameter;

        System.out.println("Passed URL:" + uri + "?" + parameter);

        HttpConnection hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);

        Commons.print(hc.getResponseCode() + ":" + HttpConnection.HTTP_OK
                + ":" + hc.getResponseMessage());

        if (hc.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
            hc = null;
            return null;
        }

        InputStream inn = hc.openInputStream();

        if (inn == null)
            return null;

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inn);

        String st = "";

        while ((st = readLine(in)) != null) {
            buf.addElement(st);

        }

        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }

        if (hc != null) {
            hc.close();
            setStatus(DataMembers.okStatus);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + ex.toString());
        setStatus(DataMembers.failStatus);
        buf = null;
    }

    return buf;
}
```

Does Blackberry requires BIS connection for making a network call? I am not appending any manual connection String to my URL.

Comment: you have to add connection parameters to the url. then only it will work. refer http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Network%20API

Comment: In my case if i am accessing direct TCP then do i want to include as "deviceside=true;apn=xxx;tunnelauthusername=;tunnelauthpassword="? also if i adding some parameters still it will be appended at the URL end right not at the parameter end? eg) http://test.aspx?param1=true

Comment: no need. check the code sample given in my blog. you only need to check weather its from wifi/direct/mds